# juju status timeout error 111 connection refused please help

Tags: juju, cloud

i am setting up juju local environment using getting started tutorials everything go smooth until i reboot my physical machine after reboot

when i tried to bootstrap its says already bootstrapped but i cant see status

see my status

```
 $ juju -v status
2013-06-16 17:49:03,643 DEBUG Initializing juju status runtime
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@712: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.4.5
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@716: Client environment:host.name=ubuntu
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@723: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@724: Client environment:os.arch=3.8.0-25-generic
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@725: Client environment:os.version=#37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:47:07 UTC 2013
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@733: Client environment:user.name=user
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@741: Client environment:user.home=/home/user
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@log_env@753: Client environment:user.dir=/home/user
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@786: Initiating client connection, host=10.0.3.1:48315 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=0x7fe71e2ea850 sessionId=0 sessionPasswd=<null> context=0x2bcb640 flags=0
2013-06-16 17:49:03,659:4613(0x7fe71a60f700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1697: Socket [10.0.3.1:48315] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2013-06-16 17:49:06,996:4613(0x7fe71a60f700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1697: Socket [10.0.3.1:48315] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2013-06-16 17:49:10,332:4613(0x7fe71a60f700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1697: Socket [10.0.3.1:48315] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2013-06-16 17:49:13,669:4613(0x7fe71fce5740):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_close@2522: Freeing zookeeper resources for sessionId=0

Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: txzookeeper.client.ConnectionTimeoutException: could not connect before timeout
2013-06-16 17:49:13,669 ERROR Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: txzookeeper.client.ConnectionTimeoutException: could not connect before timeout

2013-06-16 17:49:13,669 ERROR could not connect before timeout
```

see  [raw log](http://paste.computersnyou.com/raw/7)

Answer (score 2):

Machines should be kept between bootstraps, but sometimes that's not the case. You'll need to destroy the environment using `juju destroy-environment` and then re-bootstrap.